# Results for IN and EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table `Table_hold` and `table_pass` and I am using the following query to find out if any id in Table_pass exists, then delete the same from Table_hold.
I am using below query:

```sql
delete from Table_hold
        where  EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Table_pass pass
            WHERE id = pass.id );
```

Is there something wrong with this query? Even though there is Id=4 in table_hold and it's not there in table_pass, it still it got deleted from table_hold.

Below are the dummy tables I created:

```
create table Table_pass(id1 number);
create table table_hold(id1 number);

insert into table_pass values(1);
insert into table_pass values(2);
insert into table_pass values(3);
insert into table_hold values(4);


 delete from Table_hold
 where  EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Table_pass pass
 WHERE id1 = pass.id1 );
```

This query deletes one row with ID 4 in table_hold.

Comment: I have ran into performance issues with that subquery in a where clause.  I have found that doing a join is much more performant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like below

```
delete from Table_hold t1
 where  EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Table_pass t2
 WHERE t2.id1 = t1.id1 );
```

Answer (score 5):

Qualify *all* column references!

```
delete from Table_hold
    where exists (select 1
                  from Table_pass p
                  where p.id = table_hold.id
                 );
```

This subquery:

```
where EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Table_pass pass
              WHERE id = pass.id
             );
```

has a reference to `id`.  How is it resolved?  Well, from the inside out.  So this is equivalent to:

```
where EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Table_pass pass
              WHERE pass.id = pass.id
--------------------^ NOT table_hold
             );
```

The solution is to get in the habit of qualifying all column names.

Comment: So where EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Table_pass pass
              WHERE pass.id = pass.id
--------------------^ NOT table_hold
             ); this will return 1 always ?

Comment: @MansiRaval . . . The return value doesn't matter.  `EXISTS` only checks if a row is returned.

Comment: @MansiRaval `EXISTS` subqueries don't return anything from the select list; please don't assume they do. Instead, Oracle uses the correlation in the predicate of the subquery to decide if a row is present or not. So that `will return 1 always` statement is nonsensical; it's more like, with your current unaliased query, `the correlation will always return true`.